# Order table by column and get row number

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

In my database, I have table `wp_postmeta`, example:

```
| meta_key | meta_value |  post_id   |
---------------------------------
   points  |     12     |  23
   points  |     2      |  18
   lorem   |     ipsum  |  92
   points  |     8      |  15
```

I want to order `points` by `meta_value` and get the row number of a specific `post_id`. Basically a rank system, with highest number at the top.

For example, ordering `points` by `meta_value`:

```
| meta_key | meta_value |  post_id   |
---------------------------------
   points  |     12     |  23
   points  |     8      |  15
   points  |     2      |  18
```

So, `post_id` with value `15` will be **rank 2**.

What SQL query can I use to achieve this *with* optimisation in mind?

### What I've tried so far

So far, I have achieved this via query:

```
$query="
    SELECT post_id,FIND_IN_SET(
                  post_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( post_id ORDER BY meta_value * 1 DESC)
                          FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                          WHERE meta_key ='points')
                       ) AS `rank`
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key ='points'
    AND post_id = '".$post_id."'
    ";

$result  = $wpdb->get_row($query);

$rank = $result->rank;
```

Works fine. *However*, this query is very slow.

How can I make this query faster?

EDIT: Here is a list of indexes in this table:

[image]

Comment: *What I've tried so far* should be a standard on this platform. +1

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points when it is eligible.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas Latest version. MySQL 8.

Comment: Then why don't you use ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() window function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html and https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/

Comment: @forpas Can you please post an answer with this approach, using my code as reference?

Comment: Do you want "dense rank" or not?  Please provide the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) (or [`RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) if there are ties) window function:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY meta_value + 0 DESC) `rank` 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'points' 
ORDER BY `rank`
```

If you want the rank of a specific `post_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY meta_value + 0 DESC) `rank` 
  FROM wp_postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = 'points' 
) t
WHERE post_id = '15';
```

Or:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY meta_value + 0 DESC) `rank` 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'points' 
ORDER BY post_id = '15' DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @HenrikPetterson do you mean that you want only the rank of post_id = 15?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to **only** know the rank of post_id = 15 (or basically the ability to target one specific post_id)...

Comment: I ran a speed test on this vs my original approach, and there is barely any difference unfortunately. Is there an approach where the query will perform faster, which was my original question? Thanks.

Comment: This is the index setup of this particular table: https://i.imgur.com/QReQbZj.png

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I don't think that any method to obtain a rank position other than a window function would prove better. Your actual problem is that `meta_value` must be converted to a number in the ORDER BY clause of ROW_NUMBER(). This makes the index on `meta_value` useless.

Answer (score 1):

If `meta_value` where stored as a number, the following might be the fastest approach:

```
select count(*) + 1
from wp_postmeta pm
where pm.meta_key = 'points' and
      pm.meta_value > (select pm2.meta_value
                       from wp_postmeta pm2
                       where pm2.meta_key = 'points' and
                             pm2.post_id = 15
                      );
```

This could take advantage of indexes on `wp_postmeta(meta_key, post_id, meta_value)` and `wp_postmeta(meta_key, meta_value)`.

However, `meta_value` is probably a string so the `>` comparison does not work.  One option is a generated column, converting the value to a number.  I'm not sure if modifying the data model is something you want to do.

The goal is to avoid sorting by a non-index key.  Another method does something similar, but like this:

```
select count(*) + 1
from wp_postmeta pm cross join
     (select pm2.meta_value
      from wp_postmeta pm2
      where pm2.meta_key = 'points' and
            pm2.post_id = 15
     ) pm2
where pm.meta_key = 'points' and
      (pm.meta_value + 0) > (pm2.meta_value + 0);
```

with an index on `wp_postmeta(meta_key, post_id, meta_value)`.  This should be an index lookup for `pm2` and then an index scan for the `points` records for the outer query.

Comment: I tested both examples. You are correct, the `meta_value` is a string, so the first code didn't work. The second one did, but it is barely faster than the query posted in my question. Is it possible to convert `meta_value` to int in the query rather than adjusting the database structure? Adjusting the database index structure may not be favorable given that this is a WordPress platform. So am I out of viable options with this in mind? Stellar answer btw. EDIT: Table index setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8CXs.png

Comment: @HenrikPetterson . . . The first version may not return the correct results, but how fast is it?

Comment: The first version is slightly _slower_ than the second one.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson . . . Interesting.  I wonder if that is due to string comparisons (even on very short strings) being more complex than integer comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' ORDER BY meta_value+0 DESC
```

For the rest of this problem, a simple bit of php will suffice:

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_postmeta;

CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta
(meta_key VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,meta_value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,post_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,UNIQUE KEY(meta_key,meta_value)
);

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES
('points','12',23),
('points','2',18),
('lorem','ipsum',92),
('points','8',15);
*/

  require('path/to/pdo/connection/stateme.nts');
  $query = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'points' ORDER BY meta_value+0 DESC";
  $data = $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);


echo array_search('15',$data)+1;

?>
```

Outputs: 2

Comment: How: It's faster because it takes less time than your query. Why: Because it doesn't have  unnecessary functions that cannot use indexes and subqueries.

Comment: Please see my updated question. EDITED: "I want to order `points` by `meta_value` and get the row number of a specific `post_id`. "

Comment: Great. This is what the query above does.

Comment: But how do I target `post_id` with value `15`?